# What are the treasure maps for?

Tags: fez

How many are there, and what are they used for? Are they a cipher for something?

Comment: Hi @sean, I've removed the XBLA tag from your questions about Fez because our current tagging policy is to only use the platform tag for platform-specific questions or questions *about* the platform. As Fez is only available on XBLA, the tag is not needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I was only using it since there was no _Fez_ tag before.

Comment: No problem, you took the right steps in this case. As long as you include the title of the game somewhere in your question when first posting a question about a game with no tag yet, one of our users will come along and create the tag for you.

Comment: If you look closely at the maps it is a map of an area: it tells you where treasure is.

Comment: Where do I input the QR code from the blank map ? In which room do I press the RTs and LTs ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are nine treasure maps, found in treasure chests. They show hidden routes and solutions, usually for anticubes.

[image: Treasure Maps]

- Use first four together towards [the skull artifact puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62527/21177) ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTO-bua8IEw)).
- Use the next three to find [hidden platforms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62680/21177).
- The map with the Polytron logo is used in the [candle room](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62515/21177).
- The blank map has a QR code on the reverse side (translates to RT RT RT LT RT RT RT LT).

Comment: Since this was the part I was missing: To use a map, press the jump button.