# What does this QR Code hidden in the soundtrack mean?

Tags: fez

Since some people were saying that there would be things hidden in the soundtrack, I played a little with "Sonic Visualiser".

In the track "Spirit", I've found a QR Code at the end:

[image]

After cleaning it:

[image]

> 1955 1958 1960 1961 1967 1969 1971 1977 2003 2005

What does it mean?

(It appears that others have [also found it](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/961239-fez/62594884).)

Comment: They appear to be dates, can I have my rep now?

Comment: Yay, thank you! I never would have thought without you. ~_~ And seriously?

Comment: Have you checked other songs? Curious if there's anything in 'Reflection' in relation to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62515/what-is-the-secret-to-the-burnt-treasure-map-with-the-polytron-logo-the-candle)

Comment: Years the developers (and a couple of their children) were born?  Polytron's site doesn't exactly show how many people are in their staff, so I can't really check this.

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what it means yet, but look what I found http://pastebin.com/WJ3L99UW

Answer (score 6):

These numbers represent years of significant space exploration achievements:

- 1955 - "Space Race" began
- 1958 - NASA was founded
- 1960 - Apollo program conceived
- 1961 - First man in space
- 1967 - Outer Space Treaty signed
- 1969 - First man on the moon
- 1971 - First Apollo lunar rover launched; First Mars rover launched
- 1977 - First Voyager space probe launched
- 2003 - Columbia space shuttle disaster
- 2005 - Deep impact probe launched

This was pointed out by swam2222 on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/961239-fez/62594884?page=5), although some of swam2222's indicated milestones diverge from the ones that I've indicated here.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be only one of many secret images embedded in the soundtrack.

[image: List of clues believed to be related to the monolith puzzle]

It's widely believed these, and many other clues in the game, lead to the solution to the [monolith puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62515).  Unfortunately, it's [still unknown](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77173) how the puzzle is supposed to be solved, so no one knows for sure.