# How do I finish the room with many useless doors (mausoleum)?

Tags: fez

I found a room with about 50 doors arranged in four rows of four on each side of the cube, but with some removed/blocked. Every door I have gone through has brought me to a different door in the same room, but the world map shows that there is an exit to another room. Which of the doors should I go through to get to the next room?

[image: Mausoleum]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Enter the marked red doors on the sides that correspond with the treasure maps in the order below:

[image: Treasure map #1]
[image: Treasure map #2]
[image: Treasure map #3]
[image: Treasure map #4]

The "C" symbols represent

> the [numbers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) one through four.

It isn't necessary to have the maps in your inventory.

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question after I had all of the maps, but I didn't realize what they were for.

Answer (score 0):

I've finished this puzzle - follow the instructions.
Find all four treasure maps that say rectangles. Every rectangle is a door.
Use the number artifact and go in every dark door - just make sure which side it is is right. Notice which side it is by noticing the treasure maps won't have doors everywhere, but, there are sides with the doors in the same place.
And just follow the treasure maps into four secret doors and by numbered order. But remember to go in the dark doors!
To learn the numbers, "visit what are the numbers in fez". Besides the first answer, it will show the list of numbers in fez.