# Will the water go on forever, or is there some secret eventually?

Tags: fez

I just got my first anti-cube in a room where I had to throw four purple blocks with unique patterns on them in order to make yellow "power" lines flow in a bigger block.

I decide to try swimming in the pink (light purple?) water below it, but it goes on forever. Is there some secret if you swim for an hour or something?

I left my controller stuck and he swam for 20 minutes but it just kept going. Had to quit and come back (which started me back on the island). Made me wonder...

Answer (score 1):

It just goes on forever (like, for example, the infinite climb room). Nothing special about that either, you just have the ability to keep going.

Comment: Which is pretty amazing if you ask me BTW. I mean you have an infinite world that you can nonetheless *rotate*. My hat is off to the developer.

Comment: And I suspect that rotating the world would have been a faster way back to the island than resetting the game. :)

Comment: @fluffy, nah, rotating didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as anyone has reported, the only room with benefits from swimming out to the side of the screen is the one with the skull artifact ([after the mausoleum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62527/21177)). It was worth a try.

Comment: but it's pretty easy to see that there's something to swim to in the skull artifact room. You never have to swim out blindly.